# RegEx for no whitespace at the beginning and end

Tags: angularjs, regex, regex-negation

I want to design an expression for not allowing whitespace at the beginning and at the end of a string, but allowing in the middle of the string.

The regex I've tried is this:

```
\^[^\s][a-z\sA-Z\s0-9\s-()][^\s$]\
```

Comment: How is angular relevant? What kind of regexp? For JavaScript, as defined in ECMA-262? Do you use a regex literal in your js code? Why don't you just describe the language in words. something like this: "the set of words that do not start or end with whitespace." But what about the empty word?

Comment: the regular expression will be hard to read and understand. This expression would be much simpler: `str.trim() === str`

Answer (score 51):

This should work:

```
^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$
```

If you want to include character restrictions:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9-()]+(\s+[-a-zA-Z0-9-()]+)*$
```

Explanation:

the starting `^` and ending `$` denotes the string.

considering the first regex I gave, `[^\s]+` means `at least one not whitespace` and `\s+` means `at least one white space`. Note also that parentheses `()` groups together the second and third fragments and `*` at the end means `zero or more of this group`.
So, if you take a look, the expression is: **`begins with at least one non whitespace and ends with any number of groups of at least one whitespace followed by at least one non whitespace`.**

For example if the input is 'A' then it matches, because it matches with the `begins with at least one non whitespace` condition. The input 'AA' matches for the same reason. The input 'A A' matches also because the first A matches for the `at least one not whitespace` condition, then the ' A' matches for the `any number of groups of at least one whitespace followed by at least one non whitespace`.

' A' does not match because the `begins with at least one non whitespace` condition is not satisfied. 'A ' does not matches because the `ends with any number of groups of at least one whitespace followed by at least one non whitespace` condition is not satisfied.

If you want to restrict which characters to accept at the beginning and end, see the second regex. I have allowed a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and () at beginning and end. Only these are allowed.

Regex playground: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 10):

This RegEx will allow neither white-space at the beginning nor at the end of your string/word.

```
^[^\s].+[^\s]$
```

Any string that doesn't begin or end with a white-space will be matched.

**Explanation:**

1. `^` denotes the beginning of the string.
2. `\s` denotes white-spaces and so `[^\s]` denotes *NOT white-space*. You could alternatively use `\S` to denote the same.
3. `.` denotes any character expect line break.
4. `+` is a quantifier which denote - *one or more times*. That means, the character which `+` follows can be repeated on or more times.

You can use [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) as RegEx cheat sheet.

Comment: How can we make it work without 3 character limit? So even if user enters one character it should pass validation

Answer (score 9):

In cases when you have a specific pattern, say, `^[a-zA-Z0-9\s()-]+$`, that you want to adjust so that spaces at the start and end were not allowed, you may use lookaheads anchored at the pattern start:

```
^(?!\s)(?![\s\S]*\s$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s()-]+$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here,

- `(?!\s)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if (since it is after `^`) immediately at the start of string there is a whitespace char
- `(?![\s\S]*\s$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, (since it is also executed after `^`, the previous pattern is a lookaround that is not a consuming pattern) immediately at the start of string, there are any 0+ chars as many as possible (`[\s\S]*`, equal to `[^]*`) followed with a  whitespace char at the end of string (`$`).

In JS, you may use the following equivalent regex declarations:

```
var regex = /^(?!\s)(?![\s\S]*\s$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s()-]+$/
var regex = /^(?!\s)(?![^]*\s$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s()-]+$/
var regex = new RegExp("^(?!\\s)(?![^]*\\s$)[a-zA-Z0-9\\s()-]+$")
var regex = new RegExp(String.raw`^(?!\s)(?![^]*\s$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s()-]+$`)
```

If you know there are no linebreaks, `[\s\S]` and `[^]` may be replaced with `.`:

```
var regex = /^(?!\s)(?!.*\s$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s()-]+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cFhHQK/1).

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['a  b c', ' a b b', 'a b c '];
var regex = /^(?!\s)(?![\s\S]*\s$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s()-]+$/;
for (var i=0; i<strs.length; i++){
  console.log('"',strs[i], '"=>', regex.test(strs[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 7):

if the string must be at least 1 character long, if newlines are allowed in the middle together with any other characters and the first+last character can really be anyhing except whitespace (including @#$!...), then you are looking for:

```
^\S$|^\S[\s\S]*\S$
```

explanation and unit tests: https://regex101.com/r/uT8zU0

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
^[^\s].+[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I look for something similar but to apply for multi language web forms. The unicode topic is important. I read that with Javascript is no so effective, but it is with PCRE. I have this code:
```/[^\s]([\p{L}\-' ][^\s]){1,30}/``` 
I included a hyphen, an apostrophe because they are included in some english names, but might not be necessary, I am not sure, are they part of `\p{M}` ?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
^\S.+\S$
```

This will match any string that doesn't begin or end with any kind of space.

Comment: `.` will match `\n` or not based on the multiline flag and the string will have to be at least 3 characters long...

Comment: Not work if there be just 1 character.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^\s].+[^\s]$
```

That's it!!!! it allows any string that contains any caracter (a part from \n) without whitespace at the beginning or end; in case you want \n in the middle there is an option s that you have to replace `.+` by `[.\n]+`

Comment: it need two char to match

Answer (score 1):

pattern="^[^\s]+[-a-zA-Z\s]+([-a-zA-Z]+)*$" 
This will help you accept only characters and wont allow spaces at the start nor whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex for no white space at the begining nor at the end but only one between. Also works without a 3 character limit :

`\^([^\s]*[A-Za-z0-9]\s{0,1})[^\s]*$\` - just remove {0,1} and add `*` in order to have limitless space between.

Comment: At the moment I can add only 2 words. How can I remove this limitation and to be able to enter how many words I want ?

Answer (score 1):

As a modification of @Aprillion's answer, I prefer:

```
^\S$|^\S[ \S]*\S$
```

- It will not match a space at the beginning, end, or both.
- It matches any number of spaces between a non-whitespace character at the beginning and end of a string.
- It also matches only a single non-whitespace character (unlike many of the answers here).
- It will not match any newline (\n), \r, \t, \f, nor \v in the string (unlike Aprillion's answer). I realize this isn't explicit to the question, but it's a useful distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Letters and numbers divided only by one space. Also, no spaces allowed at beginning and end.

```
/^[a-z0-9]+( [a-z0-9]+)*$/gi
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a reliable way to do this is just to specify what you do want to allow for the first character and check the other characters as normal e.g. in JavaScript:

```
RegExp("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z- ]*$")
```

So that expression accepts only a single letter at the start, and then any number of  letters, hyphens or spaces thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

If we do not have to make a specific class of valid character set (Going to **accept any language character**), and we just going to prevent spaces from Start & End, The must simple can be this pattern:

```
/^(?! ).*[^ ]$/
```

Try on HTML Input:

```css
input:invalid {box-shadow:0 0 0 4px red}
/* Note: ^ and $ removed from pattern. Because HTML Input already use the pattern from First to End by itself. */
```

```html
<input pattern="(?! ).*[^ ]">
```

##### Explaination

- `^` Start of
- `(?!...)` (Negative lookahead) Not equal to ... > for next set
- Just Space / `\s` (Space & Tabs & Next line chars)

  - `(?! )` Do not accept any space in first of next set (`.*`)
- `.` Any character (Execpt `\n\r` linebreaks)
- `*` Zero or more (Length of the set)
- `[^ ]` Set/Class of Any character expect space
- `$` End of

Try it live: https://regexr.com/6e1o4

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^0-9 ]{1}([a-zA-Z]+\s{1})+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

-for No more than one whitespaces in between , No spaces in first and last.

```
^[^0-9 ]{1}([a-zA-Z ])+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

-for  more than one whitespaces in between , No spaces in first and last.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers introduce a limit on the length of the match.  This can be avoided using Negative lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9\s])*?(?<!\s)$
```

This starts by checking that the first character is not whitespace `^(?!\s)`. It then captures the characters you want `a-zA-Z0-9\s` non greedily (`*?`), and ends by checking that the character before `$` (end of string/line) is not `\s`.

Check that lookaheads/lookbehinds are supported in your platform/browser.

Comment: I am using the reactive form, that pattern helps me to solve this issue "^(?!\\s)(?![^]*\\s$)[a-zA-Z0-9\\s()-]+$"

Answer (score 0):

use `/^[^\s].([A-Za-z]+\s)*[A-Za-z]+$/`. this one. it only accept one space between words and no more space at beginning and end

Answer (score 0):

### Here you go,

```
\b^[^\s][a-zA-Z0-9]*\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]*\b
```

---

- \b refers to word boundary
- \s+ means allowing white-space one or more at the middle.

Answer (score 0):

```
(^(\s)+|(\s)+$)
```

This expression will match the first and last spaces of the article..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`^([^\s].+[^\s])$|^\S{1,2}$`

To allow at least one character, but no white space at end and beginning.