# How to keep spaces in between the words in address field regular expression but need to show error if we give space in the begining and ending

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
 public addressPattern: string = "^([^\s]*[A-Za-z0-9][\s]{0,1})*$";
```

this is how i written but it allowing the space in the begining and ending also.which i need to show error at that time.

Comment: Try removing the quotes and replacing them with forward slashes, ex. `public addressPattern = /^([^\s]*[A-Za-z0-9][\s]{0,1})*$/;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx for no whitespace at the beginning and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974942/regex-for-no-whitespace-at-the-beginning-and-end)

Comment: the data type is string so need to give the double quotes

Comment: Exactly the same thing but its not working which i uses from thehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974942/regex-for-no-whitespace-at-the-beginning-and-end

Comment: im still working on it  "^([^\s]*[A-Za-z0-9][\s]{0,1}[^\s])*$";if i keep like this ,it takes whitespace in the begining and in the end also

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling this, and an example of a string that passes that you want to fail?