# Regular expression alphanumeric with dash and underscore and space, but not at the beginning or at the end of the string

Tags: php, regex

This regex lets me have a string with alphanumeric, dash, underscore, and space chars in my string:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$
```

However, I need it to prevent string starting and ending by space. How can I do it?

Comment: The answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974942/regex-for-no-whitespace-at-the-beginning-and-end). Also, a tip: always put `-` inside character classes at the start or end to avoid weird issues, especially in PHP regex.