# RegExp for input that doesn't begin or end in spaces

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to test user input that doesn't begin with or end in spaces, note that I am not trying to return the match.

I am aiming for a JavaScript-less solution so that the website can be used on web browsers like “Brave,” or used by users that activate a JavaScript blocker like “NoScript.”

It is impossible for my client to input a tab, newline, or other space like character.

The input is on 1 line, multiline is irrelevant.

I am allowing spaces within the input, just not at the beginning or end.

Examples of what should work:

> “lorem ipsum”
>
> “lorem ipsum dolor”

Examples of what should fail:

> “ lorem ipsum ”
>
> “abc    ”

I'm pretty sure I'll need a negative lookbehind and lookahead, but I still haven't found a solution.

Some **failed** Regular Expressions I've come up with so far, while using [regexr.com](//regexr.com):

```
^(?<=[^ ]+).+(?=[^ ]+)$

^(?<! +)[ \w]+(?! +)$

^(?<! +)[^ ]+(?! +)$

^ {0}.+ {0}$

^([^ ]*).+([^ ]*)$

^\S*$
```

Comment: Could you just [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) it instead of detecting it?

Comment: This should answer your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974942/regex-for-no-whitespace-at-the-beginning-and-end

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974942/regex-for-no-whitespace-at-the-beginning-and-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this too (uppercase S).

`[code] ^\S(.*\S)?$ [/code]`

Comment: Enforces 2 character minimum. If anyone gets a 1 character minimum, I'll accept that instead, but at this point, we should flag my question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `trim()` in the beginning and end of the input value?

Source : [trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is being used on a page that doesn't allow JavaScript, so JQuery isn't an option. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, what platform you want this to work if not from JS or JQ?

Comment: It's inside an HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const exp2 = /^\w+.*\w+$/
console.log(exp2.test("lorem ipsum")); // true
console.log(exp2.test("lorem ipsum dolor")); // true
console.log(exp2.test(" lorem ipsum ")); // false
console.log(exp2.test("abc    ")); // false

// or the opposite:

// (?: ) - non-capturing group
// ^ - start of string
// \s+ - one or more whitespace characters
// .+ - any sequence of characters
// | - OR
// .+ - any sequence of characters
// \s+ - one or more whitespace characters
// $ - end of string
const exp = /(?:^\s+.+|.+\s+$)/;

console.log(exp.test("lorem ipsum")); // false
console.log(exp.test("lorem ipsum dolor")); // false
console.log(exp.test(" lorem ipsum ")); // true
console.log(exp.test("abc    ")); // true
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot accept this. This doesn't solve my problem at all. Actually... this is exactly the opposite, can it be made to negate what it accepts right now?

Comment: Updated with even simpler negated expression.

Comment: Very short, almost what I need, but enforces a minimum of 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern may be solve your problem:

```
^[^ ](.*?)[^ ]$
```

```html
<form>
<input pattern="^[^ ](.*?)[^ ]$" required>
</form>
```

Comment: I overlooked the lazy quantifier, this is the simplest solution I've encountered yet.

Comment: Actually, I've gotten it work with /^[^ ].+[^ ]$/ now, is there any difference between them?

Comment: Your new updated version doesn't allow spaces in between words.

Comment: The original `/^[^ ](.*?)[^ ]$/` is okay, your answer is equal to ray hatfield's answer. If my client is inputting only 1 character, chances are that they aren't actually trying to do what the form is requesting from them.

Comment: Okay. I got it. You were right to use `/^[^ ].+[^ ]$/` Regex.

Comment: The smallest I've gotten is `^\S+$`, but this doesn't allow spaces in between.

Comment: `^\S(.*?)\S$` this may be shorter