# What is the way to combine two regexes?

Tags: regex

All I try to do doesn't work. I can't combine this two regexes:

```
^(?!(.)\1+$).{8,40}$ //this doesn't let to create word with only one symbol like '111111111111' or enter code here`fffffffffffff`
^\s|\s$ //this checks if first or last symbol is space
```

So I need regex that will include first one and opposite of the second one, e.g.:
word should be more than 8 symbols, not be containing only one symbol and first and last symbol shouldn't be space.

Comment: You say "all I try" - what do you try? Please explain what you are doing, what sample strings you test your patterns against, what regex engine you are using, so that we could help you.

Comment: I try to combine them one after second, using 'AND' operator like `?=`

Comment: `?=` is not AND operator. If you mean you are using `(?=....)` , it is a positive lookahead, and it is the right way, but please show the expression in full.

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed full statement. I try this (?!(.)\1+$)^(?!=\s)(?!=\s$).{8,40}$

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! but actually I mean, my word (password) can be more that 8 symbols (works), all symbols not one symbol (works), and first and last symbol can't be space. I check this regex on regex101.com, and it matches to this ' dfdsfsdfgfdfgfdfd '. that's why it is hard to find out solution

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the `=` in your lookaheads, they make `=` required before whitespaces, `^(?!(.)\1+$)(?!\s)(?!.*\s$).{8,40}$`, see https://regex101.com/r/neQhQv/1

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you post this in answer so that I mark it as correct?

Comment: I [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60782571/3832970) and explained, and showed a demo.

Comment: I mean here, in this question.