# Regex for no leading and trailing space only middle space in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Like tried with this sample with no special character:

```
let x = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z\s0-9]+$'); // with no special char

x.test('Hello world'); // should return true
x.test('Hello world with something'); // should return true

x.test(' Hello world'); // should return false
x.test('Hello world '); // should return false
x.test('Hello  world'); // should return false
```

Comment: `const x = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/`

Comment: you need to escape the backslash since you're using quotes --- `'^[A-Za-z\\s0-9]+$'`

Comment: for regex you should use either a regex literal: `let x = /^[A-Za-z\s0-9]+$/` or a raw string: `let x = new RegExp(String.raw\`^[A-Za-z\s0-9]+$\`)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that link is not exactly duplicate of this question. Some of them almost the answer but with another propose. As i google it, there is no good pattern that follow all characters, so i made this: https://regexr.com/6e1o4 for question owner. Please reopen it to i can explain it.

Comment: @MMMahdy-PAPION It is a valid dupe reason. However, even for your reading of this question, there is [another dupe reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974942/) with several matching answers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you. This new link you add made it right.

Comment: _"no leading and trailing space only middle space"_ who cares about the middle ? This `^(?!\s)(?!.*\s$).*` fairly simple. What is the Duplicate about ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70857303/7514010